# jquery.load() page with inline script duplicates script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On my web page I have index and other php pages that are loaded to a div within index with $().load. These little pages have some inline js code like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready($("#dialog").dialog());
</script>
```

So in every click on a link that loads this page I get +1 popup on page load. The problem isn't specifically with this dialog, it is with all scripts, they wildly duplicate. Is there some sort of $().on function so I can delegate those builders and leave the loaded page without inline script? Or is there something like require_once?

Comment: You can try transferring the scripts from the inline pages to the main index, and then remove them from the inline pages.

Comment: Done that, most of js is loaded in index, but the problem is it wont work on later loaded pages if I don't use something like $().on. And I am not able to find any analogues to do such thing with .dialog().

Comment: Please place everything in an anonymous function when using `$(document).ready();` Like this: `$(document).ready(function() {$("#dialog").dialog()});` See the documentation: [The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I had it like this everywhere, except for this file. Thanks for the heads up.